# Suppose $U\leq V,W\leq V$. Prove that $U$ and $W$ are contained in $U+W$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space and $U\leq V,W\leq V$
Prove that $U$ and $W$ are contained in $U+W$.

I do not understand the requirement of the question. Is it prove that $U,W$ is the subset of $U+W$ or prove that $U+W$ is a subspace of $V?$

Comment: You have to prove that they are subspaces of $U+W$.

Comment: @Shash Is it prove that $U,W$ is the subset of $U+W$ sufficient to prove that they are subspaces of $U+W$?

Comment: Yes, since $U$ and $W$ are spaces themselves, it is sufficient to prove they are subsets.

Comment: Do you mean $U\subseteq V$, $W\subseteq V$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is half of the solution:

$$U+W=\{u+w:u\in U, w\in W\}\supseteq \{u+0:u\in U, 0\in W\}=U$$

Your task is to prove that $U\subseteq U+W$ and that $W\subseteq U+W$.

Answer (score 0):

I guess subspace. But then $0 \in U\cap W$ since a subspace must contain $0$. Thus if $u \in U, w \in W \to u = u+0 \in U+W \text{and } w = w+0 \in U+W$.